# ARCore – Convert ARCamera Image to Texture2D (RGB)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I have an ARCore Camera in Unity and I want to convert its frames to Texture2D (RGB) for further processing. I tried ComputerVision script but I can't understand it nor can I make it work. If anyone can please help me through Code

Note: 640x480 size is good too as long as it is an RGB texture2D.

Comment: I have tried really hard but failed to convert it, if anyone can give me an opener it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There's two great posts for you to read.

> The first one is a `StackOverflow` post:

[How to take picture with camera using ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191513/how-to-take-picture-with-camera-using-arcore).

> And the second one is `OpenGL ES` series:

[Introducing basic texturing for Android](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm purely referring to Unity, I think stackoverflow added few tags by itself but i updated it. sorry if you got the wrong idea